# how to convert json date value to "dd/mm/yyyy" format

Tags: java, json, date

I have a return result like this:
o is :

dates `[Object { date=12, day=4, hours=0, more...}]`

```
JSONObject o=somefunction();
response.getWriter().write(o.toString());
```

and this response like `[object Object]`

but i need to this date format like "dd/mm/yyyy" format.

How i convert this value?

Comment: Please check the formatting of your question!

Comment: @DevlshOne the link you gave is for javascript, yet he seems to want to do this in java code...

Comment: If I understand correctly that you want to do this in java, why don't you look at joda-time?

Comment: show us the complete json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON has no notion of dates. The best way is either use the unix timestamp oder ISO datetime. Nothing else, nothing custom.